# Cython throws same runtime errors on all Python scripts

Tags: python, cygwin, syntax-error, cython

I did a `pip install --upgrade cython` without problems on Cygwin.

However, every script I try to run with cython, gives me the following runtime errors, and GINMF (Google Is Not My Friend):

```
$ cat /tmp/hello_cython.py
print("hello cython")

$ cython /tmp/hello_cython.py -o /tmp/hello_cython.exe

$ /tmp/hello_cython.exe
/tmp/hello_cython.exe: line 1: /bin: is a directory
/tmp/hello_cython.exe: line 65: syntax error near unexpected token `a+k,'
/tmp/hello_cython.exe: line 65: `          PyCode_New(a+k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)'
```

Anyone knows what is going on?

**My Environment:**

- Cython version 0.22
- CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 DellIns14 1.7.33-2(0.280/5/3) 2014-11-13 15:45 i686 Cygwin

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Where did you get this code from? This seems so wrong :)

Comment: As I wrote, @cel, I just did a `pip install`, and then tried to use the insalled cython to execute print "Hello World".
To which code do you refer - the cython that pip installed, or my "hello world" Python script?

Comment: The problem is that you seem to assume that `cython` outputs a `.exe` file, which is not the case. Moreover trying to run a exe file from a unix shell seems weird. The output of the `cython` command is actually a `.c` file which you have to compile. I would suggest looking for a good tutorial on `cython`.

Comment: Thanks @cel: I'll try and get a good introduction to cython.

Answer (score 1):

OP acted under the assumption that cython will produce a compiled output, when it actually producesses a `c` file, which needs to be [compiled and linked](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html).